# Palladium catalyst

Tags: catalysis, organometallic-compounds

Recently I found the following [question by sam](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/how-to-produce-dry-pure-oxygen):

> I'm supposed to produce dry and pure oxygen using the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide with a manganese dioxide catalyst.
>   $$\ce{2H2O2(aq) -> 2H2O(l) + O2(g)}$$
>
> The gas will be collected in a bottle by downward displacement of water. How can I safely move the oxygen gas through the drying agent without mixing in atmospheric gas?

Based on that I am asking me, if and how palladium could catalyze the reaction?

Comment: Your title states sth about Pd, your first question says sth about Pd but below you only write sth about MnO2 and how to move the gas. Where is the connection?

Comment: This question is *suspiciously* similar to [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34938/how-to-produce-dry-pure-oxygen)

Comment: I don't think that it is a duplicate. It's about what a change of the catalyst would bring to the system.